# Automatically redefine comment box dimensions to match the background image in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, dimensions

In Excel, say I choose an image, test.jpeg for example, as the background of a comment. I want the comment box to take the dimensions of test.jpeg. Since I plan on having hundreds of such comments, my question is: is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tinkered together a VBA macro. Open your VBA editor with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and paste the below code under *sheet1*. Execute the macro with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

### What the macro does

1. Ask user for a path to a picture which he wants to insert (can be jpg, bmp or png)
2. Load that picture as a [`WIA.imageFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630506(v=vs.85).aspx). Later we use `objImage.Height` and `objImage.Width` to get the real picture dimensions.

   This method was the shortest one I've found to get dimensions in pixels (other VBA methods may give you [twips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip). They are a horrible invention)
3. Insert a blank comment on the currently selected cell if no old comment already exists there
4. Set the chosen picture as background image for the comment shape
5. Resize the comment shape dimensions so the picture perfectly fits

```vb
Sub InsertComment()

    Dim strImagePath As Variant
    Dim objImage As Object
        
    strImagePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Picture, *.jpg; *.png; *.bmp")
    If strImagePath = False Then Exit Sub
                
    Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    objImage.LoadFile strImagePath
    
    With ActiveCell
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then .AddComment ("")
        .Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture strImagePath
        .Comment.Shape.Height = objImage.Height * 0.75
        .Comment.Shape.Width = objImage.Width * 0.75
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Utterly Cool!! ..........i have never seen the *WIA.ImageFile* object before

Comment: Very cool indeed! Exactly what I was looking for. Just a remark: it seems like the dimensions of the comment are *bigger* than the dimensions of the image. For example, when I look at the details of one of the jpeg image I have, I see that its dimensions are 290 x 420 pixels. The comment has dimensions 10.24 x 14.82 cm. But, according to [this converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html), it should be 7,67 x 11,11 cm.